# How to persist a subset of data from a larger set in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

A network call returns a very large json file. However, I just need to use a small portion of this through out the entire app. What is the best strategy on using a small amount of data for several fragments and activities ?

I tried to use shared preferences, but that does not store objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sharing complex data structures or objects, I would extend Application by making a custom sub class. Application object (as the name implies) is accessible to all Activities, even when app transitions from one to another. Below is a very simple example, just to show you the idea. You can modify/adjust that to your needs.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
   private X x;

   public static void setX(X x) { ... }
   public static X getX() { ... }
}
public class ActivityA extends Activity {

    ...
    MyApplication.setX(x);

}
public class ActivityB extends Activity {

    ...
    X x = MyApplication.getX();

}
```

X can be  a collection, data structure, or any object for that matter.

When extending Application, you need to declare it in the manifest. You can find information on how to do that.

Comment: but why make it a sub-class ? what is the purpose for that ?

Comment: That is how Android works. Each app has an Application object, if you want to a add anything thing, you just extend it and then in the Manifest point to your extended class. This is basic OOP.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the required data from your JSON as a `String` and then pass it as an extras parameter to the Activities and Fragments that need it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SomeActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("YOUR_DATA_KEY", yourJsonString);
startActivity(intent);
```

and then extract it back again at the Activities and Fragments that need it:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String yourJsonString= intent.getStringExtra("YOUR_DATA_KEY");
```